# How to replace in frontend Buffer.from(data, 'base64')?

Tags: browser, frontend, base64

To convert a binary string into an image, I use the Buffer.from(data, 'base64') construction in Node JS, it works perfectly. Now I'm trying to pass a similar string to the browser using this

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${data}" />
```

and it doesn't work. In the API the ${data} looks like this:

```
"thumbnailPhoto":{"type":"Buffer","data":[255,216,255,225,12,239,69,120,105,102,0,0,73,73,42,0,8,0,0,0,16,0,0,1,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn’t find anything smart, I just changed it and decided to do this formatting on the backend side (Node JS)

```
  const getUsersAttr = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ad = new ActiveDirectory(connLDP)
    ad.findUsers(fltLDP, function (err, users) {
      if (err) {
        reject(console.error(JSON.stringify(err.message)))
      } else if (!users || users.length == 0) {
        resolve('No users found')
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          if (users[i].thumbnailPhoto) {
            users[i].thumbnailPhoto = Buffer.from(users[i].thumbnailPhoto).toString('base64')
          }
        }
        resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users)))
      }
    })
  })

  return await getUsersAttr
}
```